# Wait until the user hits 'Restore' after a Chrome crash

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an Chrome Extension.
If the Chrome browser crashes for whatever reason, re-opening again would usually ask the user if he/she wants to Restore the previous session, and re-open the windows.

Is there any event, hook, or API I can use to wait until the user hit the Restore button, or know if chose not to restore and start from scratch?

Current Ugly solution is:

1. Save the amount of windows open before crashing.
2. On startup after crashing, wait until the amount of open windows is >= to the amount saved.
3. If there's a window open that has anything else than a single tab with the homepage/newtab, then continue, as the user chose not to restore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the (relatively) new [`chrome.sessions` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sessions) and experiment with it.

`chrome.sessions.onChanged` is the closest you have - it should be fired at restore.

However, there's no indication whether there are crash-restoration sessions pending user approval as opposed to simply normally closing a window, and no indication whether a window was restored after a crash or deliberately by the user.

Generally, there are no events specific to crash-restoration to the best of my knowledge. So you still need some heuristics to see if you want to wait.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it seems the chrome.sessions.onChanged event gets triggered as soon as chrome starts and berfore the user hits the Restore button.
Can't use it as a solution.